# Force viewDidLoad to fire on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, viewdidload, loadview

I have two window app and while I present first window I would like the view in second window to load and prepare content for later in background.

I've tried to use method `loadView` but Apple says you should not call this method directly.

So far I've chosen to use the view's method `userInteractionEnabled` which actually implicitly 
calls `viewDidLoad` method.

Is there an elegant way to force `ViewControllers` `viewDidLoad` method to fire before it should naturally (when window is key and presented)?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can just call `[viewController view];`.

The [documentation for UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621460-view?language=objc) explains how the view property is lazy-loaded and that `viewDidLoad` is called after the view is loaded.

Comment: So simple yet so powerful :) Thanks!

Comment: Nice! At first I tried viewController.view but it gave a warning but sending it the message "view" this way doesn't give a warning at all

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, but is there a documentation/explanation on how this works and what it does?

Comment: @Spartacus9 Yes the [documentation for `UIViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621460-view?language=objc) explains how the `view` property is lazy-loaded and that `viewDidLoad` is called after the view is loaded.

Answer (score 34):

In iOS 9, Apple finally fixed this:

```
// Loads the view controller's view if it has not already been set.
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
public func loadViewIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Here is the real answer

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 2.0**, with same result of @Carl Veazey's solution:

```
let viewController = MyCustomViewController()
_ = viewController.view
```

Comment: I am trying this with swift and it's not working... Did this stop working with the newer versions of iOS/Swift?

Comment: What do you mean with "newer versions of iOS/Swift"? Swift 3.0? I didn't test Swift 3.0 yet, so I don't know If this approach still works.

Comment: I am using swift 2.2, and this is not working for me... The only difference between my code and yours is that instead of instatiating the View Controller myself, I am calling the method instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier of the storyboard instance.

Comment: My bad, I was instantiating a NavigationController, that's why it wasn't working... Thank you

Comment: Ok, no problem. I've just test and confirm that It still works! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global instance for that controller(May be in `AppDelegate`) and call the method you want to perform the action for. Then While pushing to that controller don't create a new instance Just use the instance you have created for global use.