# TableViewController's viewDidLoad not firing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, viewdidload

I've been following this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/) to have a Slide-Out Menu. I've added a TableViewController which will display a list of articles. For some reason the `viewDidLoad` is not firing.

In this tutorial a `SideViewController` controls which controller will be displayed, in case of having a `segue` with identifier "showPhoto", it will load a specific image.

```
// Set the photo if it navigates to the PhotoView
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showPhoto"]) {
    PhotoViewController *photoController = (PhotoViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    NSString *photoFilename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_photo.jpg", [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    photoController.photoFilename = photoFilename;
}
```

I thought of recreating the same thing for the `TableViewController` and trying to force the `viewDidLoad` of the controller as seen here [Force viewDidLoad to fire on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703659/force-viewdidload-to-fire-on-ios) but it still didn't work:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showList"]) {
    TableViewController *tableController = (TableViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    [tableController view];
}
```

**TableViewController viewDidLoad:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Change button color
    _sidebarButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.1f alpha:0.9f];

    // Set the side bar button action. When it's tapped, it'll show up the sidebar.
    _sidebarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
    _sidebarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);

    // Set the gesture
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];

    // Set this view controller object as the delegate and data source for the table view
    self.listTableView.delegate = self;
    self.listTableView.dataSource = self;

    // Create array object and assign it to _feedItems variable
    _feedItems = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    // Create new HomeModel object and assign it to _homeModel variable
    _homeModel = [[HomeModel alloc] init];

    // Set this view controller object as the delegate for the home model object
    _homeModel.delegate = self;

    // Call the download items method of the home model object
    [_homeModel downloadItems];
}
```

What's weird is that the other two Controllers being used (`PhotoViewController` and `MapViewController`) work as expected...maybe there's some settings than I'm missing.

I've literally just started on iOS, can't work this out unfortunately.

[Project Download](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18543481/SidebarDemo.zip)

Comment: maybe you are looking for -viewWillAppear: or -viewDidAppear:?

Comment: make sure that correct class is being instantiated

Comment: @Michael thanks for the suggestion, I've tried moving the `viewDidLoad` code (added to question) to `viewDidAppear` (as suggested by @Goppinath as well), did not change though

Comment: @j.grima : share this project somewhere. it'll be faster to identify the problem. it's probably a segue related issue.

Comment: @staticVoidMan just added a link to the project, thanks

Comment: I also tested it. staticVoidMan's answer should fix it. `viewDidLoad` gets called.

Comment: @Unheilig thank you, I've updated my code and `viewDidLoad` is called...this might be a different issue but just wondering if the TableView displayed any data for you.

Comment: @j.grima Welcome. Unfortunately no, you will soon get an `NSInvalidArgumentException` exception after it gets called.

Comment: @Unheilig actually I've managed to display the items...`TableViewController.m` had `[self.listTableView reloadData];`, changed that to `[self.tableView reloadData];` and it worked, what's left is having the button working

Comment: @j.grima My focus was rather on the method call, so I didn't delve into the exception. But good that you report back for the benefit of others.

Comment: @Unheilig no worries! Thanks again for your help. Everything is still quite new to me, I'm more into web and software development through C# but I'm sure I'll get there :) This helped me understand a few things as well.

Comment: I had the same problem and my issue was, I forgot writing class name in Identity Inspector of my Controller in Storyboard.
I solved it by just adding class name there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues with `TableViewController` (*as per the project archive you shared*)

### TableViewController.h

```
@interface TableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, HomeModelProtocol>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *sidebarButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *listTableView;
@end
```

should be:

```
//subclass should be UITableViewController
@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController <HomeModelProtocol>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *sidebarButton;
//not needed
//@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *listTableView;
@end
```

---

### TableViewController.m

in `-viewDidLoad`, observe:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    //...

    //crashes when adding gesture to a tableView (this is not part of the core problem
    //but will be one if not handled) for now... comment it
    //[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];

    //not needed as it's done via IB (but this is not part of the problem)
    //self.listTableView.delegate = self;
    //self.listTableView.dataSource = self;

    //...
}
```

---

### Storyboard

Select that `UITableViewController`:

- Specify custom class as `TableViewController` <sup>(via Identity Inspector)</sup>
- Set `Top Bar` to `Translucent Navigation Bar` <sup>(via Attributes Inspector)</sup>
- Add a `UINavigationItem`
- Add a `UIBarButtonItem` on it and set it to menu (*as you've done in the other `viewControllers`*)

  - Connect the `IBOutlet` object `sidebarButton` to this `UIBarButtonItem`

---

### SidebarViewController.m

in your `-prepareForSegue:sender:` method, if you aren't passing data to `TableViewController` then you need not do anything

```
- (void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *) segue sender: (id) sender
{
    //...

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showList"]) {
        //TableViewController *tableController = (TableViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;

        //this is definitely not needed whether you pass data or not
        //[tableController view];
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: I realised the subclass issue just as you posted this :) `viewDidLoad` is now being fired. Just wondering if the table displayed any data when all the code was changed...might be an entirely different issue though.

Comment: Got it to work :) I'm just stuck in the last part of the `UIBarButtonItem` - "Connect the `IBOutlet` object `sidebarButton` to this `UIBarButtonItem`"

Comment: Figured it out :) I dragged the small circle next to `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *sidebarButton;` in the `TableViewController.h`onto the button in the `Storyboard`, thanks again for you help @staticVoidMan

Answer (score 2):

Move your code to

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

hope it will work.

Comment: I did as you suggested but still nothing, I will update my question with more code maybe there's something missing